# How to use search and replace all the matching words in a sentence in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have to search and replace all the words starting with @ and # in a sentence. Can you please let me know the best way to do this in PHP. I tried with

`preg_replace('/(\@+|\#+).*?(?=\s)/','--', $string);`

This will solve only one word in a sentence. I want all the matches to be replace.

I cannot `g` here like in perl.

Comment: give us example.. "I want ...SOMETHING... to become ....OTHERTHING..."..

Comment: it is not letting me to paste the sentence as the sentence has words starting with @ (so and so) and # (so and so)

Comment: Page 3 ----------requested URL: http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=news&geocode=51.5002,-0.1262,10mi&rpp=5&page=3&since_id=3.1688471418938E+17
0- RT @/WiredUK: Social charity platform Believe.in launches: http://t.co/HCuPrOlf0U by @liatclark
1- Ex-PC jailed for selling Sun stories http://t.co/1Fsy4Ds1VB good job as well.
2- White @/space broadband brings the web to communities lacking electricity http://t.co/jC2Ra9akNg
3- RT #/WiredUK: Social charity platform Believe.in launches: http://t.co/HCuPrOlf0U by liatclark

Comment: i have just added / after @ and # as it was not permitting for multiple of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A word **starting** with a character implies that it has a space right before this character. Try something like that:

```
/(?<!\S)[@#].*(?=[^a-z])/
```

Why not use `(?=\s)`? Because if there is some ponctuation right after the word, it's not part of the word. Note: you can replace `[^a-z]` by any list of unallowed character in your word.

Be careful though, there are are two particular cases where that doesn't work. You have to use 3 `preg_replace` in a row, the two others are for words that begin and end the string:

```
/^[@#].*(?=[^a-z])/
/(?<!\S)[@#].*$/
```

Comment: `(?<=\s)` wouldn't match words at the start of string. You can use `(?<!\S)` for that.

Comment: But after this solution , i have another doubt . In a sentence i want to delete everything except words. I mean all the urls, @ so and so , # of so and so, and %'s. everything. I just want to retain proper alphabetical words.. so that i can so the spell check on them

Comment: @Oltarus : yes you are rite. Thank you for the help. The solution works wel. My problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

[`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) replaces all matches by default.  If it is not doing so, it is an issue with your pattern or the data.

Try this pattern instead:

```
(?<!\S)[@#]+\w+
```

`(?<!\S)` - do not match if the pattern is preceded by a non-whitespace character.

`[@#]+` - match one or more of `@` and `#`.

`\w+` - match one or more word characters (letter, numbers, underscores).  This will preserve punctuation.  For example, `@foo.` would be replaced by `--.`.  If you don't want this, you could use `\S+` instead, which matches all characters that are not whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
  $string     = "@Test let us meet_me@noon see #Prasanth";
  $new_pro_name = preg_replace('/(?<!\S)(@\w+|#\w+)/','--', $string);
  echo $new_pro_name;
```

This replaces all the words starting with `@` OR `#`

Output: `-- let us meet_me@noon see --`

If you want to replace word after `@` OR `#` even if it at the middle of the word.

```
  $string     = "@Test let us meet_me@noon see #Prasanth";
  $new_pro_name = preg_replace('/(@\w+|#\w+)/','--', $string);
  echo $new_pro_name;
```

Output: `-- let us meet_me-- see --`

Comment: Hmm, the word `meet_me@noon` would be replaced by `meet_me--`, that's a problem.

Comment: @Oltarus : What is the problem with that? it is replacing to `meet_me--`

Comment: The problem is that with your answer, an e-mail address, for example, which is a common "word" with a @ in the middle, will be replaced. The question was on words the **begin** with @ or #.

Comment: This does not work.. It removes all the words in the sentence.. and i get a blank.

Comment: I just want to remove any word that begins with a @ or a #

Comment: @Ranjitha : Getting blank !!!!!...Just copy and paste the code above and execute, You will get the output